# Exercise on submartingales: is $\phi(X_n)$ a submartingale, given some assumptions on $(X_n)$? Is the following solution correct?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, martingales, jensen-inequality

> Let $X=(X_n)_{n>0}$ be a submartingale. Show that if $\phi$ is convex and nondecreasing on $\mathbb{R}$ and if $\phi(X_n)$ is integrable for each $n$, then $Y_n=\phi(X_n)$ is also a submartingale.

**MY SOLUTION**

We have that:

$1)$ $\mathbb{E}(|X_n|) < \infty$, each $n$;

$2)$ $X_n$ is $\mathcal{F_n}$-measurable, each $n$;

$3)$ $\mathbb{E}(X_n|\mathcal{F}_m) \geq X_m$ a.s., each $m \leq n$;

We have to show that, *given that*:

$4)$ $\phi^{''} > 0$;

$5)$ $\phi^{'} \geq 0$, that is: if $x < y$, then $\phi(x) \leq \phi(y)$;

$6)$ $\mathbb{E}(\phi(X_n)) < \infty $;

*then*:

$1.1)$ $\mathbb{E}(Y_n=\phi(X_n)|\mathcal{F}_m) \geq Y_m = \phi(X_m)$ a.s., each $m \leq n$.

**FIRST**, since $\phi$ is nondecreasing (**assumption $5)$**), given assumption $3)$, for each $m\leq n$ and almost surely it holds that:
\begin{equation}
\phi(\mathbb{E}(X_n|\mathcal{F}_m)) \geq \phi(X_m) = Y_m
\end{equation}

**SECONDLY**, since $\phi$ is convex (**assumption $4)$**), by Jensen's inequality it holds that:
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}(\phi(X_n)=Y_n|\mathcal{F}_m) \geq \phi(\mathbb{E}(X_n|\mathcal{F}_m)) \geq \phi(X_m) = Y_m 
\end{equation}

which exactly corresponds to $1.1)$.

*Is the above reasoning correct?*

Comment: Convexity doesn't need differentiability (though it's a.e. twice differentiable, but that's a hard theorem). If you have Jensen's then it is sort of immediate, if you don't then any convex function is pointwise a supremum of affine functions, then use linearity.

Comment: Please try to state the actual question in the title: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/321264.

Comment: Of course, sorry. Done right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your argument works fine but your understanding of convexity is not correct. Convex functions are not defined through second derivatives. They are defined by the inequality $\phi (tx+(1-t)y) \leq t\phi (x)+(1-t)\phi (y)$  and a convex function need not even have first derivative at very point. However Jensen's inequality is valid for these functions even if they are not differentiable.

Comment: Yes, of course, I was mistaken as to convexity definition. 
I think you mean that a twice differentiable function nonnegative on the entire domain is convex, but not always the opposite holds true, don't you @Kavi Rama Murthy?